# Does the morphology of the insertion of the gluteus minimus to the greater trochanter impact the likelihood of being affected by a tendinopathy?

Tags: tendinopathy, tendons, hips

{1} noted two different  morphologies for the  insertion of the gluteus minimus to the greater trochanter:

> Two morphologies noted: The majority (11/14) were long, thin, and crescent shaped and ran medial to lateral and concave facing inferiorly, while a few (3/14) were bowtie in shape. [quote from Table 1 below from {1}]

Does the morphology of the insertion of the gluteus minimus to the greater trochanter impact the likelihood of the gluteus minimus being affected by a tendinopathy?

[image]

---

References:

- {1} Philippon, Marc J., Max P. Michalski, Kevin J. Campbell, Mary T. Goldsmith, Brian M. Devitt, Coen A. Wijdicks, and Robert F. LaPrade. "Surgically relevant bony and soft tissue anatomy of the proximal femur." Orthopaedic journal of sports medicine 2, no. 6 (2014): 2325967114535188. https://scholar.google.com/scholar?hl=en&as_sdt=0%2C5&q=Surgically+Relevant+Bony+and+Soft+Tissue+Anatomy+of+the+Proximal+Femur&btnG= ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/26535335 ; https://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC4555602/ ; https://doi.org/10.1177/2325967114535188

Comment: Good question. I’m finding references about variants of other aspects of hip anatomy giving rise to tindinopathy and hip pain, but I haven’t found much relating to variations in the gluteus minimus insertion footprint. I’ll keep looking! :)